# Why the input size with material design is not restricted by the enclosing div?

Tags: material-design

I am trying out material design and I do not know what is missing here.

I want to use a text input and a button.

The input is within a `div`. I expected the input size is limited by the enclosing div.

In this case I have set the enclosing div's width to 50px.

However the input just expanded and took up the full width.

Why?

Screen shot:

[image]

Code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>



<div width="50px" padding="5px">
<input placeholder="Event Name" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="billing email" data-trekkie-id="email_field" data-shopify-pay-handle="true" data-autofocus="true" data-backup="customer_email" aria-describedby="checkout-context-step-one" aria-required="true" class="field__input" size="30" type="text" name="checkout[email]" id="checkout_email"/>
</div>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons right">check</i>OK</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the columns layout disponible in materialize:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-icons/3.0.1/iconfont/material-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
<div class="col s5">
<input placeholder="Event Name" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="billing email" data-trekkie-id="email_field" data-shopify-pay-handle="true" data-autofocus="true" data-backup="customer_email" aria-describedby="checkout-context-step-one" aria-required="true" class="field__input" size="30" type="text" name="checkout[email]" id="checkout_email"/>
</div>
</div>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn"><i class="material-icons right">check</i>OK</a>
```

Link for documentation: https://materializecss.com/grid.html